# Insert stmt with a Select and additional Params

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to have a "mixed" SQL Insert like the following?
I want to be able to get one value from another table (that needs a param) and then enter in 2 more params.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblquestions (userID, questionText, questionAnswer) VALUES (
    Select userID FROM tblusers WHERE userEmail = (?),?,?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $userEmail, $question, $answer);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception($conn->error);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the above code before asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary.  Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO tblquestions(userID, questionText, questionAnswer)
    Select userID, ?, ?
    FROM tblusers
    WHERE userEmail = (?);
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but instead of the two params in the select statement, I want them to be other params loaded by PHP that are not part of the select.

Comment: @Pnchappy92 . . . You can plug parameter values or constants in a `select` statement.